# Adding a hash of the string to the same line in Python 3

Tags: python, python-3.x, hashlib

I'm trying to write a script which would take a password txt file (with cleartext passwords in each line) as input. The new output txt file would include passwords in cleartext and hash (SHA1) in each line as:

password:5baa61e4c9b93f3f0682250b6cf8331b7ee68fd8
password2:2aa60a8ff7fcd473d321e0146afd9e26df395147
...

So far, this is what I have:

---

```
wordlist = input("Input name of wordlist file: ")
result = input("Enter name of result file: ")

with open(result, 'w') as results:
    for word in open(wordlist).read().split():
        hash = hashlib.md5(word.encode())
        hash.update(bytes(word, 'utf-8'))
        results.write(word + ':' + hash + '\n')
```

The error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "rainbow.py", line 11, in <module>
    results.write(word + ':' + hash + '\n')
TypeError: must be str, not _hashlib.HASH
```

Thanks a bunch!

Comment: Does it work? If not, how is it deficient? What is the question?

Comment: It doesn't work and I would love to hear you opinion on how to fix the code.

Comment: `...how is it deficient? What is the question?`

Comment: The Taceback says that you are trying to concatenate a function to a `str` - it doesn't like that, it is expecting a `str`.

Comment: You probably want `hash.hexdigest()` instead of just `hash` here.

Comment: To get a str. You must not write `hash`, but `hash.hexdigest()`. And btw. Do not name your variable `hash`. By doing so you reassign what is otherwise a [built-in function](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#hash).

Comment: With the line `hash.update(bytes(word, 'utf-8'))` - you are hashing `'passwordpassword'`, is that intended?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`hash` is an instance of `_hashlib.HASH` (as the traceback says), so you cannot simply add it to a string. Instead you have to generate a string from `hash` using `hash.hexdigest()`:

```
import hashlib

word = 'password:5baa61e4c9b93f3f0682250b6cf8331b7ee68fd8'
hash = hashlib.md5()
hash.update(bytes(word, 'utf-8'))
print(word + ':' + hash.hexdigest() + '\n')enter code here
# password:5baa61e4c9b93f3f0682250b6cf8331b7ee68fd8:5c56610768a788522ad3502b58b660fd
```

Used in your original code, the fix would look like this:

```
wordlist = input("Input name of wordlist file: ")
result = input("Enter name of result file: ")

with open(result, 'w') as results:
    for word in open(wordlist).read().split():
        hash = hashlib.md5()
        hash.update(bytes(word, 'utf-8'))
        results.write(word + ':' + hash.hexdigest() + '\n')
```

edited based on comments by @OndrejK. and @wwii

Comment: Actually, it's not a built-in at that time any more as it got reassigned. What the traceback says is it's an instance of `_hashlib.HASH` which indeed got assign to this `hash` two lines up with `hash = hashlib.md5()`.

Comment: @OndrejK. thanks for pointing this out, I corrected my answer

Comment: Maybe also show your solution using the OP's example code.